# How to execute a shellscript when having specific hardware listed in xinput

Tags: shell-script, hardware

I'd like to run a xinput to command to configure my mouse sensitivity everytime i open my terminal. 
I know how to do that and both commands inside the if statements work, but i don't know how to set the correct if condition to run those commands. 

I only want to run those two commands if the system can somehow identify my specific mouse model.
I tried the following code but it does not work.

```
if [ xinput == 'Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse' ]; 
  then
    xinput --set-prop 'pointer:''Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse' 'libinput Accel Profile Enabled' 0, 1
    xinput --set-prop 'pointer:''Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse' 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.5
fi
```

What should i write inside the `if [ ??? ];` statement to make it work?

Comment: `if [ -n "$(xinput | grep 'Logitech G203 LIGHTSYNC Gaming Mouse')" ]; then` also check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931244/checking-if-output-of-a-command-contains-a-certain-string-in-a-shell-script

Comment: The grep solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot! If there's something more appropriate i'll watch it, for now this is the best.